# android.hardware.telephony breaks installation on the emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest, uses-feature

We're currently revising our application manifest to explicitly use the `uses-feature` attribute to declare all its dependencies on hardware and software APIs.

Since we expect the user to have mobile Internet, we set `android.hardware.telephony` to `true`, but now the app fails to install on the emulator. The error message is:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_FEATURE]
```

There is no additional information, not even in the device logs, but I could figure out by trial and error that the telephony feature was causing it.

Since the emulator has support for telephony functionality (you can even simulate dispatching a call), why does this break? And even if it correctly reports that it doesn't support telephony, shouldn't it be obvious that `uses-feature` was meant to target real devices, not the emulator?

I'm actually quite confused about this attribute now in general, since [its documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) seems to imply that it only affects filtering rules for Android Market. I can't see where it mentions that `uses-feature` has a direct impact of the installability of an app, which seems to go way beyond the merely declarational/informational nature the docs attribute to it.

Maybe it's not a good idea to use it after all? Our build server doesn't execute anymore, since installation to the emulator now always fails...

Comment: what is exactly the error message you have ?

Comment: sorry, added the error message we're seeing.

Comment: That's weird, but do you really want to place this restriction? A user might have good wifi coverage and not opt for a monthly mobile bill.

Comment: well, that's a fair question, but the problem is that there is no way to define either-or-requirements, and the user certainly needs some form of Internet access to use our app. And we believed that requiring Wi-Fi would be more restrictive than requiring mobile data, since we do not target tablets, only smartphones.

Comment: I've seen this too, with the "wifi" feature. But this only fails on a 2.2 emulator (presumably as that's when this tag started to be enforced); prior platform versions work. Still, very annoying.

Comment: @Matthias do you need `android.hardware.telephony` or you just need to make a call from your app?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need to use a more recent Emulater with more features supported,or alternatively you can do the following :

1.Comment out or remove the following lines from your Manifest XML file

```
<!-- COMMENT ME  -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" />
```

OR

2.Add the following :

```
<!-- UNCOMMENT ME  and add android:required="false"  -->
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
```

You should be good to go if you do it  correctly.

[image: See Sample]

Answer (score -1):

I have an app that uses telephony and works fine with the 2.2 emulator and I presume you have already set the required attribute to false in your manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
```

If that's the case, my guess is that there is *another* feature or permission declared in your manifest that isn't present in the emulator and causing the error.  Hunt it down through trial and error.

Comment: I don't quite understand--if the app requires telephony, shouldn't that feature be set to `true`? The problem, as I see, is really that while the emulator does support telephony, it reports to Android that it doesn't.

Comment: required defaults to true.  if you declare use of a feature that is required and the device doesn't support it, you won't be able to install and/or you will get filtered in the market.

I've had to handle the emulator as a special case in my apps when dealing with TelephonyManager.